# Update ListView in AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I want to create ListView which every 4 seconds add item and set focus on last item.
Problem is that my Fragment wait for asynctask is over and only then show(all time asynctask work its white screen)

```
 public class LogFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    private ListView lvList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private UpdateTask mTask = null;
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.log_fragment, container, false);
        lvList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvLog);
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            list.add(values[i]);
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lvList.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "LogFragment:OnCreate");
        mTask = new UpdateTask();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mTask.execute();
    }
```

And AnyncTask -

```
 public class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        int temp = 10;

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            getSherlockActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (temp-- > 0) {
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
                            adapter.add("Lol" + String.valueOf(temp));
                            lvList.setSelection(lvList.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
                            Log.d("myLogs", "Added from Async");
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Add code that loops through JSONArray and adds to adapter here

        }
    }
```

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) to update the data in your Adapter, this will update what is shown in your ListView. Also, calling runOnUiThread from doInBackground is a bad idea, that method was designed to perform all the heavy-lifting outside the UI thread, and onPostExecute is designed to make changes to the UI once your Task is done executing... I would suggest the following :

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
    adapter.add("Lol" + String.valueOf(temp));
    Log.d("myLogs", "Added from Async");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // Add code that loops through JSONArray and adds to adapter here
    lvList.setSelection(lvList.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Without runOnUi it's not work(only the original thread that created a view hierarchy listview can touch...).
And i want to see result of adding bit by bit, not all string at once

Comment: I edited my answer, move the call to setSelection in onPostExecute as well.